# How to add an item only if no other items exist with the same name in the arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How would I go about only inserting an item if the item does not have the same name as the other items in the arraylist within my insertUniqueItem() method?

```
    public void insertUniqueItem()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart();
        Item a = new Item("Kraft Cheese", 4, "\"Best Cheese in Town!\"");
        Item b = new Item("Bottle of Water", 2.50, "\"Refreshing Water!\"");

        sc.insertItem(a);
        sc.insertItem(b);

        sc.printInvoice();
        sc.insertUniqueItem();

        sc.print();

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

        System.out.println("Total Price: $" + df.format(sc.getTotal()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if an item with the same name already exists in your list:

```
public void insertUniqueItem(Item item) {
    if(!contains(item)) {
        cart.add(item);
    }
}

private boolean contains(Item item) {
    for(Item i : cart) {
        if(i.getName().equals(item.getName())) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I love how I didn't have to add hashs or lists to do so. It works :)

Answer (score 11):

I would probably use a `LinkedHashMap<String, Item>` instead, where the key is the name of the item. That way:

- You still get to preserve ordering
- You can easily and efficiently check whether there's already an entry for a given item name.

You'd have something like:

```
if (!map.containsKey(item.getName()) {
    map.put(item.getName(), item);
}
```

This only works if you want *all* items to be unique in terms of name though. If you sometimes want to allow a duplicate name and sometimes not, you probably *do* want a list, and then you could have something like:

```
boolean containsItemName(ArrayList<Item> items, String name) {
    for (Item item : items) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you're using Java 8, you could use a stream-based solution:

```
boolean containsItemName(ArrayList<Item> items, String name) {
    return items.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getName().equals(name));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wanted to stick with only using my arraylist. I see how this would work though. Once again, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your Item class to have the equals and hashcode methods as follows:

```
public class Item{

    private String name;


    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o instanceOf Item and ((Item)o).getName().compareTo(name) == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return name.hashCode();
    }

}
```

You can now use the contains method of the arrayList to determine if another item exists with the same name in the arrayList or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wanted to stay with only using an arraylist and not using a hash to complete it.

Comment: The hash is needed only so that the arraylist can determine if the item exists in it. It doesn't utilize a hash table

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a Set in your ShoppingCart instead of a List. Set will manage the unicity of your items. Make sure to have equals method override in your Item class

Comment: That works if items are naturally equal just by name - but if there can be two items with the same name but different other values, it would be somewhat odd for them to be equal, I suspect.

Comment: true. this is why equals method has to be override to define the rules of unicity before

Comment: I think you've missed my point - if you're overriding it to be equal just on the basis of name, you may well find that elsewhere you want it to be equal based on other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not using Set ?

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
> (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
> this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
> e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
> the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
> with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
> contain duplicate elements.

too simple :
override `equal` and `hashCode` on `Item` class :

```
class Item {
    private String title ;
    private String description  ;
    // getter & setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return Objects.equals(title,item.title) ; // Or any statement you want
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(title); //same statement like equals method
    }
}
```

Now :

```
List<Item> listCollection = new ArrayList<>();
Item a = new Item("A", "Best Cheese in Town!");
Item b = new Item("B", "Refreshing Water!");
// add items ...
listCollection.add(a);
listCollection.add(b);

Set<Item> setCollection = new HashSet<>(listCollection);
Item duplicate = new Item("B","New Description");
setCollection.add(duplicate); // Not added to setCollection
```